# Glassfish 3.1.1 cluster load balancing apache mod_jk windows 7 x64

Tags: apache2, glassfish-3, load-balancing, mod-jk, failovercluster

I am using the following configuration:

Glassfish 3.1.1 (zip version), apache 2.2.22, mod_jk 1.2.32 and Windows 7 x64.

I've got 2 physical machines. On the 1st machine there is DAS, instance 1 of Glassfish, apache with mod_jk. On the second machine there is instance 2 of Glassfish.

I read through lots of tutorials on the web, did exactly the same things and I still can't get it working. I can do session replication between two physical machines of one web application. I managed to run apache and install mod_jk. I set up http-listener on port 8009. I can see that apache redirects all requests to port 80 to 8080 used by Glassfish. However, when I type localhost/some_application it doesn't open some_application.

I looked at the logs for mod_jk. This is what I usually see there:

[Thu Feb 09 18:15:31 2012] [5532:2244] [info] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (626): connect to 127.0.1.1:8009 failed (errno=61)
[Thu Feb 09 18:15:31 2012] [5532:2244] [info] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (1008): Failed opening socket to (127.0.1.1:8009) (errno=61)
[Thu Feb 09 18:15:31 2012] [5532:2244] [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1630): (worker1) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=61)
[Thu Feb 09 18:15:31 2012] [5532:2244] [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2607): (worker1) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable), because of error during request sending (attempt=1)

Does anybody know to resolve that?

Thanks in advance.